# composite key for the table using association annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to `hibernate` and I am trying to implement a basic application that uses this schema (it does not follow the notation I just use it for clarity)

[image]

Here is the my classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "race")
public class Race {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="np_character")
public class NPCharacter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @OneToOne
    private Race race;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="main_female_character")
public class MainFemaleCharacter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @OneToOne
    private Race race;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="copulation_registry")
public class CopulationRegistry {
    // ??
    private NPCharacter npCharacter;
    // ??
    private MainFemaleCharacter femCharacter;
    private int times;
}
```

But I ran into the problem with `copulation_registry` class. I used everywhere `OneToOne` annotation, instead of using references to keys. But what I should do here? Pairs of `id_femPlayer` and `id_npCharacter` are unique.

Should I use `EmbeddedId` annotation or is it possible somehow to use association annotations to represent the same relation?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can annotate class CopulationRegistry with @IdClass

@Entity
@IdClass(CopulationRegistryKey.class)
@Table(name="copulation_registry")
public class CopulationRegistry {
    @Id
    private NPCharacter npCharacter;
    @Id
    private MainFemaleCharacter femCharacter;
    private int times;
}


public class CopulationRegistryKey{
    private NPCharacter npCharacter;
    private MainFemaleCharacter femCharacter;
}
```

Comment: But how it will handle association with `NPCharacter` tables and `MainFemaleCharacter` tables? Also I get error `could not determine type for MainFemaleCharacter at table copulation_registry for columns Column(femCharacter)`